# Python library pulp outputs approximate solution for Integer Linear Programming model of SubsetSum

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am running the following, relatively simple code, to solve the SubsetSum problem:

```
def run(self, values, target):
    # Create the model
    model = LpProblem(name="small-problem", sense=LpMaximize)

    # Initialize the decision variables
    variables = [LpVariable(f"{values[i]}", 0, 1, LpInteger) for i in range(len(values))]

#Objective function
    model += sum([variables[val] * values[val] for val in range(len(variables))])
#Constraints:
    model += sum([variables[val] * values[val] for val in range(len(variables))]) <= target

    status = model.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True, maxSeconds=10, mip=True, gapAbs=0), )

    result = list()
    for var in model.variables():
        if var.value() == 1.0:
            result.append(int(var.name))
    #     print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")
    # print(f"objective: {model.objective.value()}")
    return result
```

However, the outputted solution is only approximate! I've tried all different parameters of trying to ensure the solution must be precise. Anyone knows what I have done wrong?

Comment: May be caused by the time limit. Study the solver log carefully.

Comment: Hi Erwin. I should have added the log. However, what I am seeing in the log is ''Optimal value found'', and when I then compute the sum, it is less than the target value. Naturally, I know the solution is not optimal, since I compare it to a determinstic algorithm, that does in fact achieve the target value.

Comment: After studying the CBC log file you should (hopefully) see that the correct objective is found. But I see a problem in you code. "if var.value() == 1.0:"  is incorrect. You need to replace this by something like "if var.value() > 0.9:" as x maybe something like 0.99999 instead of 1. CBC works with floating point numbers.

Comment: Let me try it out. Thanks for the help. FYI, removing the time limit seems to make no difference though :-)

Comment: Alright, nope, that did not make the difference!

Comment: I am seeing something like:
Cbc0038I Rounding solution of -2.49996e+006 is better than previous of -2.49992e+006.

Can that have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can try to tighten the optimality tolerance a bit (or better, use better scaling).

Comment: Ahh I finally found the problem. This line in the log: Cgl0014I Postprocessing changed objective from 800000 to 800033 - possible tolerance issue - try without preprocessing